# Args not being passed through to Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, rake, task

I have a rake task that accepts an argument, :scope (below).
I call the rake task like this:

```
rake podcast:generate_inventory["new"]
```

This task used to pass the :scope arg perfectly, however, I noticed today that the arg is no longer being passed.  Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
namespace :podcast do

  task :itunes_top_300, [:scope] => :environment do |t,args|
    Podcast.podcast_logger.info("BEGIN: #{Time.now}")
    if args[:scope] == "new"
      Podcast.podcast_logger.info("NEW PODCASTS ONLY")
    end
    Podcast.itunes_top_rss
  end

  task :itunes_genres_top_300 => :itunes_top_300 do
    Podcast.itunes_genre_rss
  end

  task :site_and_feed_discovery, [:scope] => :itunes_genres_top_300 do |t,args|
    if args[:scope] == "new"
      Podcast.site_and_feed_discovery(:new_podcasts_only => true)
    else
      Podcast.site_and_feed_discovery
    end
  end

  task :social_discovery, [:scope] => :site_and_feed_discovery do |t,args|
    if args[:scope] == "new"
      Podcast.social_discovery(:new_podcasts_only => true)
    else
      Podcast.social_discovery
    end
  end

  task :fetch_episodes => :social_discovery do |t,args|
    Episode.episode_logger.info("BEGIN: #{Time.now}")
    Podcast.fetch_episodes
    Episode.episode_logger.info("END: #{Time.now}")
  end

  task :generate_inventory => :fetch_episodes do |t,args|
    Podcast.podcast_logger.info("Successful Rake")
    Podcast.podcast_logger.info("END #{Time.now}")
    Rake::Task['maintenance:daily'].invoke
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `[:scope]` bit in your definition of `task :generate_inventory`.  I suspect adding that back in will take care of everything.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks much Xavier.  Worked like a charm :)